# How do I import an SSH Private key that has pass phrase

Tags: linux, ssh

I have generated a private key with a pass pass phrase using PuTTygen on my windows machine. I know need to import that private key to a linux machine but unsure how to go about using the private key that is pass phrase protected. On a windows machine I would just open the private key with Putty Pageant which will ask me for the pass phrase, whats the equivalent on linux?

Beskee

Comment: You should use openssh.

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you need is to copy the public part of the key: to achieve this you can just copy the corresponding file. You can also copy the private key (even if I think it makes no sense), you don't need the password to copy it, but you will need it to use it.